# Remove empty values from array

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

From a database, table I select a column and saved into an array. But in the column has some empty value. Now I want to remove those empty value from the array. how can I do?

Here is the code where I get array list from a database:

```
public ArrayList<ChapterInfo> getAllResult(String tableName){

    ArrayList<ChapterInfo> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    String arg = "select "+tableName+" from "+tableName+";";

    Cursor cursor = this.database.rawQuery(arg,null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        do {
            ChapterInfo chapterInfo = new ChapterInfo(
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tableName)));
            arrayList.add(chapterInfo);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    return arrayList;
}`
```

Code is working fine. but here is some empty value in that table. but that empty row is not deletable because there is another column that column is full.

Comment: Not sure `String arg = "select "+tableName+" from "+tableName+";";` is correct.  Do you mean `String arg = "select "+tableColumnName+" from "+tableName+";";`?

Comment: Never return an implementation like `ArrayList` in a `public` method as it is an implementation detail that should be hided, you should rather return an interface like a `List` or a `Collection` instead

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply check if the string is empty or not and then add it to the ArrayList only if the string is not empty.

```
    String stringTemp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tableName))
    if(stringTemp != null && !stringTemp.isEmpty())
      arrayList.add(chapterInfo);
```

Comment: Two minor things: A) naming ... why stringTemp ... rowContent would better say what is going on B) always always always use { braces } of if/else blocks; even when it is just a one-liner.

Comment: The columnName wasn't visible so it was the placeholder which definitely would be replaced. And I will keep in mind about the braces. I generally avoid for one liners which definitely is not a good practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `arrayList.remove(element);` where element is the index of arraylist which you want to remove

OR

You can add a empty check before adding your data in arraylist like:

```
do {
    String tableData = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tableName));
    if (tableData.trim().isEmpty()){
        continue;
    }
    else{
        ChapterInfo chapterInfo = new ChapterInfo(tableData);
        arrayList.add(chapterInfo);
    }
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `Predicate` for that:

```
package question_40387644;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    public static Predicate<String> isNotNullAndNotEmpty = s -> s != null && !s.isEmpty();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> someValues = new ArrayList<>();
        someValues.add("value A");
        someValues.add("value B");
        someValues.add(" ");
        someValues.add("");

        System.out.println("List size:");
        System.out.println(someValues.size());

        System.out.println("Non-empty values:");
        someValues.stream().filter(isNotNullAndNotEmpty).forEach(s -> System.out.println("s = " + s));


        System.out.println("Empty values:");
        System.out.println(someValues.stream().filter(String::isEmpty).collect(Collectors.toList()).size());

    }
}
```

The output:

```
List size:
4
Non-empty values:
s = value A
s = value B
s =  
Empty values:
1
```